# Selenium Teamcity Chromedriver IWebDriver chrome does not launch

Tags: selenium, teamcity, selenium-chromedriver

Jammed up trying to execute selenium tests remotely. We are attempting to execute our Selenium tests on our TeamCity server. I know that is a bad idea but that's not why I am here. 
super basic Nunit selenium webdriver / chrome.

```
 [TestFixture]
public class Mytest1
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
    private string baseURL;
    private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("\"no-sandbox\"");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        baseURL = "http://example.com/";
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        try
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
        }
        Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
    }

    [Test]
    public void TheMytest1Test()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/somepage/");
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("linktest")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.container-div.caption")).Click();
    }
```

When I run this from VS I see the "starting chromeDriver ver 2.22 etc.. only local connections allowed. " The test runs 100%. 
I commit my changes to teamcity (v9.x) where I have an Nunit task runner. against the test. This is where it dies out. Testing directly on the build server I see the following in my build log.

```
    [18:07:43][Step 3/5] Starting ChromeDriver 2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b) on port 50513
[18:07:43][Step 3/5] Only local connections are allowed.
[18:08:46]
[SeleniumTests.Mytest1.TheMytest1Test] OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:50513/session timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[18:08:46]
[SeleniumTests.Mytest1.TheMytest1Test]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
   at SeleniumTests.Mytest1.SetupTest()
--WebException
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
--TearDown
   at SeleniumTests.Mytest1.TeardownTest()
```

I can it is trying to do something with chrome.exe but just won't get to it. This is the error that keeps popping up. Any ideas how to get around this? My assumptions are that this a permissions related issue but completely stuck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with your chrome options. 
`options.AddArgument("\"no-sandbox\"");` 
seems like it should be `options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");`
Also are you specifying the location of the binary?

Comment: I am chasing it down as a permissions type thing at the moment. I ran the test through the nunit console runner and the test fired up immediately on the server I need the tests to run on. I am going on the assumption that the problem might be due to the build agent running as a local service.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was that the buildagent was running as a local service. Once I changed it to run as a local user account everything worked out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been plaguing me since the release of chrome v 51. This is happening because the chrome process is getting started in session[0] which is making chrome unresponsive.  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615396

This is the bug I have been following to track the issue. A fix was supposed to be released today with Chrome v 52 but this has not fixed the issue for me. So I am unsure if the fix was actually released or if I am experiencing a different issue.